# Deploy a smart Contract on Alonzo testnet

Tags: plutus, smart-contract

Hi I have written a contract in Plutus and test it with PAB and Playground simulations.
The problem I am facing is I cannot find any proper documentation on how to deploy a contract on the test/main net.

I understand that we have serialized the Haskel Script and submit it with the transaction but I am very unclear how to do this step.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this [tutorial](https://plutus-pioneer-program.readthedocs.io/en/latest/alonzo/hello_world_script.html) yet?